# PySpark Ranking Rows Weighted for A Goal Ratio

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to rerank a scored set of students to guarantee if I took N students 
from the top of my list, I would get at least a portion in a certain category.

So if we had the input of this dataframe

```
+----------+------+-----+
|STUDENT_ID|  TYPE|SCORE|
+----------+------+-----+
|         A|female|100.0|
|         B|female| 99.0|
|         C|female| 88.0|
|         D|female| 77.0|
|         E|female| 66.0|
|         F|female| 55.0|
|         G|female| 44.0|
|         H|female| 33.0|
|         I|  male| 22.0|
|         J|  male| 11.0|
+----------+------+-----+
```

And our goal was to get .2 of my population to be male at any point, I would rerank it like so

```
+----------+------+-----+
|STUDENT_ID|  TYPE|SCORE|
+----------+------+-----+
|         I|  male| 22.0|
|         A|female|100.0|
|         B|female| 99.0|
|         C|female| 88.0|
|         D|female| 77.0|
|         J|  male| 11.0|
|         E|female| 66.0|
|         F|female| 55.0|
|         G|female| 44.0|
|         H|female| 33.0|
+----------+------+-----+
```

Now if I take my top 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 10 students from my population, I am guaranteeing that I am hitting my
.2 male ratio, but still taking the males in order of best to worst.

And even though my females have been adjusted down a little bit, I am still making sure they are taken  in order of best to worst.

Here are a few more examples.

---

Input

```
+----------+------+-----+          
|STUDENT_ID|  TYPE|SCORE|          
+----------+------+-----+          
|         A|female|100.0|          
|         B|female| 99.0|          
|         C|female| 88.0|          
|         D|female| 77.0|          
|         E|female| 66.0|          
|         F|female| 55.0|          
|         G|female| 44.0|          
|         H|female| 33.0|          
|         I|  male| 22.0|          
|         J|  male| 11.0|          
+----------+------+-----+
```

Output with 100% should be male so all of them are moved up to the top

```
+----------+------+-----+
|STUDENT_ID|  TYPE|SCORE|
+----------+------+-----+
|         I|  male| 22.0|
|         J|  male| 11.0|
|         A|female|100.0|
|         B|female| 99.0|
|         C|female| 88.0|
|         D|female| 77.0|
|         E|female| 66.0|
|         F|female| 55.0|
|         G|female| 44.0|
|         H|female| 33.0|
+----------+------+-----+
```

---

Input

```
+----------+------+-----+
|STUDENT_ID|  TYPE|SCORE|
+----------+------+-----+
|         A|male  |100.0|
|         B|female| 99.0|
|         C|female| 88.0|
|         D|female| 77.0|
|         E|female| 66.0|
|         F|female| 55.0|
|         G|female| 44.0|
|         H|female| 33.0|
|         I|  male| 22.0|
|         J|  male| 11.0|
+----------+------+-----+
```

Output with 20 % should be male but one was alread in place, so we only need to move 1

```
+----------+------+-----+
|STUDENT_ID|  TYPE|SCORE|
+----------+------+-----+
|         A|male  |100.0|
|         B|female| 99.0|
|         C|female| 88.0|
|         D|female| 77.0|
|         E|female| 66.0|
|         I|  male| 22.0|
|         F|female| 55.0|
|         G|female| 44.0|
|         H|female| 33.0|
|         J|  male| 11.0|
+----------+------+-----+
```

---

Here is the code which works for some cases, but not other cases.

It takes the input dataframe, ranks it, ranks it by type, and then adjust the ranking based on your desired ratio.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DoubleType, StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

temp_struct = StructType([
    StructField('STUDENT_ID',  StringType()),
    StructField('TYPE',  StringType()),
    StructField('SCORE',  DoubleType())
])


temp_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['A',  'female', 100.0],
    ['B',  'female', 99.0],
    ['C',  'female', 88.0],
    ['D',  'female', 77.0],
    ['E',  'female', 66.0],
    ['F',  'female', 55.0],
    ['G',  'female', 44.0],
    ['H',  'female', 33.0],
    ['I',  'male', 22.0],
    ['J',  'male', 11.0]
], temp_struct)

print('Initial DF')
temp_df.show()

window_by_score_desc = Window.orderBy(f.col('SCORE').desc())
temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('RANK', f.row_number().over(window_by_score_desc)).orderBy(f.col('RANK').asc())
print('With RANK DF')
temp_df.show()

window_by_type_rank = Window.partitionBy(f.col('TYPE')).orderBy(f.col('RANK').asc())
temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('TYPE_RANK', f.row_number().over(window_by_type_rank)).orderBy(f.col('RANK').asc())
print('With TYPE RANK DF')
temp_df.show()

def weight_for_type_and_ratio(input_df, student_type, student_ratio):
    section_size = float(1 / student_ratio)
    return input_df.withColumn('ADJUSTED_RANK', 
                               f.when(f.col('TYPE') == student_type, 
                                       (f.col('TYPE_RANK') - 1) * (section_size-1) + .5).otherwise(f.col('RANK')))


print('FINAL WITH ADJUSTED RANK DF')
weight_for_type_and_ratio(temp_df, 'male', .2).orderBy(f.col('ADJUSTED_RANK').asc()).show()
```

And this code works for some cases....
Input:

```
+----------+------+-----+
|STUDENT_ID|  TYPE|SCORE|
+----------+------+-----+
|         A|female|100.0|
|         B|female| 99.0|
|         C|female| 88.0|
|         D|female| 77.0|
|         E|female| 66.0|
|         F|female| 55.0|
|         G|female| 44.0|
|         H|female| 33.0|
|         I|  male| 22.0|
|         J|  male| 11.0|
+----------+------+-----+
```

Which gives a correctly adjusted ranked output

```
+----------+------+-----+----+---------+-------------+
|STUDENT_ID|  TYPE|SCORE|RANK|TYPE_RANK|ADJUSTED_RANK|
+----------+------+-----+----+---------+-------------+
|         I|  male| 22.0|   9|        1|          0.5|
|         A|female|100.0|   1|        1|          1.0|
|         B|female| 99.0|   2|        2|          2.0|
|         C|female| 88.0|   3|        3|          3.0|
|         D|female| 77.0|   4|        4|          4.0|
|         J|  male| 11.0|  10|        2|          4.5|
|         E|female| 66.0|   5|        5|          5.0|
|         F|female| 55.0|   6|        6|          6.0|
|         G|female| 44.0|   7|        7|          7.0|
|         H|female| 33.0|   8|        8|          8.0|
+----------+------+-----+----+---------+-------------+
```

But not for other cases, specifically when some records are already in place, and do not need adjusted.

Input DF:
Initial DF

```
+----------+------+-----+
|STUDENT_ID|  TYPE|SCORE|
+----------+------+-----+
|         A|  male|100.0|
|         B|female| 99.0|
|         C|female| 88.0|
|         D|female| 77.0|
|         E|female| 66.0|
|         F|female| 55.0|
|         G|female| 44.0|
|         H|female| 33.0|
|         I|  male| 22.0|
|         J|  male| 11.0|
+----------+------+-----+
```

Which gives the incorrect output of:

```
+----------+------+-----+----+---------+-------------+
|STUDENT_ID|  TYPE|SCORE|RANK|TYPE_RANK|ADJUSTED_RANK|
+----------+------+-----+----+---------+-------------+
|         A|  male|100.0|   1|        1|          0.5|
|         B|female| 99.0|   2|        1|          2.0|
|         C|female| 88.0|   3|        2|          3.0|
|         D|female| 77.0|   4|        3|          4.0|
|         I|  male| 22.0|   9|        2|          4.5|
|         E|female| 66.0|   5|        4|          5.0|
|         F|female| 55.0|   6|        5|          6.0|
|         G|female| 44.0|   7|        6|          7.0|
|         H|female| 33.0|   8|        7|          8.0|
|         J|  male| 11.0|  10|        3|          8.5|
+----------+------+-----+----+---------+-------------+
```

Where the adjusted rank of male I is too high.

**Any thoughts on a different approach to this problem. Not looking for much of a code change, maybe just a different thought process.**

Answer (score 0):

In case that you only want to assure that when you take N students you get a certain portion of a certain category, I think there is a much clearer solution by using [limit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.limit). Have a look at the code below:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DoubleType, StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

temp_struct = StructType([
    StructField('STUDENT_ID',  StringType()),
    StructField('TYPE',  StringType()),
    StructField('SCORE',  DoubleType())
])


temp_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['A',  'female', 100.0],
    ['B',  'female', 99.0],
    ['C',  'female', 88.0],
    ['D',  'female', 77.0],
    ['E',  'female', 66.0],
    ['F',  'female', 55.0],
    ['G',  'female', 44.0],
    ['H',  'female', 33.0],
    ['I',  'male', 22.0],
    ['J',  'male', 11.0]
], temp_struct)

#Total number of students you want to get 
total = 5
#portion of the category
fractionMale = 0.2

#simply selecting and limiting the rows for each category and using a union to get a single dataframe
temp_df.filter(temp_df.TYPE == 'male').limit(int(total * fractionMale)).union(temp_df.filter(temp_df.TYPE == 'female').limit(int(total * (1-fractionMale)))).show()
```

Output:

```py
+----------+------+-----+ 
|STUDENT_ID|  TYPE|SCORE| 
+----------+------+-----+ 
|         I|  male| 22.0| 
|         A|female|100.0| 
|         B|female| 99.0| 
|         C|female| 88.0| 
|         D|female| 77.0| 
+----------+------+-----+
```

Unfortunatly we can't use [sampleby](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sampleBy) as Spark uses [Bernoulli_sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_sampling) and it is certain that you get the expected totals of each category. I.e. the following will not always return you 5 rows with the expected fractions.

```py
total = 5
fractionMale = 0.2
countMale = temp_df.filter(temp_df.TYPE == 'male').count()
countFemale = temp_df.count() - countMale

sampleFractionMale = (total * fractionMale)/countMale

sampleFractionFemale = (total * (1 - fractionMale))/countFemale

temp_df.sampleBy("TYPE", fractions={'male': sampleFractionMale, 'female': sampleFractionFemale}).show()
```

Output:

```py
+----------+------+-----+ 
|STUDENT_ID| TYPE|SCORE| 
+----------+------+-----+ 
|         A|female|100.0| 
|         B|female| 99.0| 
|         C|female| 88.0| 
|         D|female| 77.0| 
|         F|female| 55.0| 
|         I|  male| 22.0| 
+----------+------+-----+
```